# Optimization in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, aggregate

I am writing the code in pyspark where am doing filter,join,unionall,groupby operations.

But I noticed that before groupby opration, count() function takes 9 minutes while after groupby, count() function takes 35 minutes. I need some suggestions over how to optimize the groupby clause so as to reduce the processing time.

Configuration parameters:
executor memory 12g
num-executors 50
executor cores 5
driver memory 40g
Data size around 1 TB

Code snippet for example:

```
dataframeA = hc.sql("select * from tableA")



dataframeB = hc.sql("select * from tableB")

 dataframeC = hc.sql("select * from tableC")



dataframeD = dataframeA.unionAll(dataframeB)



dataframeE = dataframeD.join(dataframeC, col1 == col2, 'left_outer')



dataframeF = dataframeE.groupby ([col1, col2]
                   .agg({
                       max("col3"),
                       sum("col4")/ sum("col5"),
                       ...
                       })
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: to be able to help you need to post your code (or at least a simplified case of it)

Comment: Added the code snippet for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using `reduceByKey` instead of `groupByKey`.

`groupByKey` will shuffle all of the data among clusters and consume a lot of resources, but `reduceByKey` will reduce data in each cluster first then shuffle the data reduced.

Comment: Yes I suspect the same that excessive shuffling is happening in group by. But is it possible to apply reducebykey here in my case where I am using all dataframes and there are some 100 columns in aggregation?

Comment: In your case, `groupBy` of DataFrame is optimized, so I don't think `reduceByKey` really works.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the shuffling in group by and aggregate operation?

Answer (score 0):

The logic itself seems ok. There are a couple of things you can try though:

You have a join and a groupby which usually suggest some shuffle. You can try reducing the number of executers, giving each more memory and cores.

In your groupby, you are using key [col1, col2]. Are these the same columns as in the join? If so then they are essentially the same column with a difference where there is no key on the left dataframe. You can therefore use col2 only and hopefully the optimizer would improve your second shuffle (use the original shuffling).

Comment: In my case, there are 3 joins and one of them is having same key as that of group by. Reducing the number of executors is not working in this case its taking same execution time.

Comment: What i noticed from web UI is last 4 stages out of 23 is taking more than half of the time. What about increasing partitions ?

Comment: Increasing the number of partitions would generally help if you have the cores to handle them. It basically increases the parallelism...